# prestashop 1.6 multistore not able to change product store wise

Tags: php, prestashop

***Here we have some case***

1. **create product with any store** :-
   product will display selected store only

**Problem**  now i want to allow in some other store too, but prestashop not given and settings like magento, which we can set product store wise.

can someone please suggest how can i figure out.

Comment: It seems that you can't do it in a convenient way, only through a database. Also, you can try to play with products duplication in a context of store groups but I'm not sure that that would work in an expectable way

Comment: no man i have to serve it my customer and they are not technical...any other way like GUI

Comment: In this case, you need to create a module which would do the job for you

Comment: yah thare is a last way for me.. but i think prestashop have to to give this feature.